# Some explanation regarding a diagram of homotopy

Tags: terminology, homotopy-theory, visualization

I found this visualization regarding homotpy in wikipedia:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Homotopy_curves.png

I would be very grateful if you could explai me all the abbreviations being used. I guess t stands for t and s for space, so that H (t,s) would be a homotopy in time t and space s. But what does gamma stand for, a given homotopy path? Would we call x and y the origo points of the homotopy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the Wikipedia page for homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) already? That might be helpful.

In the picture you link, there are two [paths](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Path_(Topology)) with endpoints $x$ and $y$. The names of those paths happen to be $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$. While $\gamma$ is a common variable for a path, I do not know where that convention comes from. The function $H$ is a homotopy between the two paths $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$. The letter $H$ is chosen to stand for homotopy. The letter $t$ is a common parameter for the paths, and can sometimes be interpreted as "time". $s$ is a common companion variable to $t$, and it may help you to remember how path homotopies like $H(t,s)$ work if you think of it as "space", but I doubt that was why $s$ was chosen here.

Note: the intent is likely for $H(t,0)=\gamma_0(t)$ and $H(t,1)=\gamma_1(t)$ for all $t$.